# Counter most_common elements as a generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator, counter

I'm using a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object. I want to get the most common elements one by one but the `most_common` method gives me the whole list of elements.
Is there any way to get this list as a generator?

Comment: It's possible to fake it, as described in my answer, but I can't help but wonder what you hope to gain by having such a generator because before `most_common()` can return anything it has to process all of its input and store the intermediate results -- so the entire list is created whether you arrange to have it returned piecemeal to you or not. In other words I don't think there's an incremental way to do the processing it does.

Comment: You are right. I have a lot of elements in the counter so I was trying to avoid creating a list with all of them.

Comment: So it sounds like you're agreeing that what you want isn't possible. Seems to me that asking for only the `n` most common element might at least reduce the size of the internal list that's created.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap `collection.Counter.most_common()` in a generator function like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common(iterable, n=None):
    return iter(Counter(iterable).most_common() if n is None else
                Counter(iterable).most_common(n))

for item in most_common('Mississippi', 3):
    print item
```

Note: While it appears that passing `None` to `collection.Counter.most_common()` is the same as passing nothing to it (a common Python idiom), the current documentation does *not* actually say that, so I have decided to err on the side of caution and use an `.. if .. else ..` conditional expression to only pass it `n` when it's not `None`, however its docstring does explicitly say "If `n` is `None`, then list all element counts".

If this slight discrepancy doesn't worry you, the above could be shortened to just:

```
def most_common(iterable, n=None):
    return iter(Counter(iterable).most_common(n))
```

Which is so short, you might just want to code `iter()` around any `Counter.most_common()` calls you have to avoid the overhead of calling an extra wrapper-function.

Regardless, the output should look like this:

```
('i', 4)
('s', 4)
('p', 2)
```

Comment: You can rewrite the function as `return iter(Counter(iterable).most_common(n))`.  Passing `None` to `most_common()` is equivalent to omitting the parameter, and the `for` loop can be more succinctly expressed using `iter()`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Thanks for reminding me about `iter()`, however I don't completely agree with you about the optimization regarding passing `None` to `Counter.most_common()`.

Comment: The docstring says "If `n` is `None`, then list all element counts."

Comment: @SvenMarnach: The separate documentation (Windows Help file in this case) says "If n is not specified, most_common() returns all elements in the counter" -- but like you, I'd tend to believe the docstring since there's one less level of indirection.

Comment: The documentation is often not very clear on whether keyword arguments are allowed, and what the default values for default parameters are.  The Python guys are aware of this, so they usually consider changing these things an incompatible change, even if not documented.  And regarding docstrings vs. external documentation:  Usually, the external documentation tends to be more detailed than the docstrings, and is considered the authorative documentation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Changing which thing, the function/method or the documentation?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: BTW, in this case what it would do if you actually passed it `None` is more ambiguous than usual because logically, it could also mean the same as saying give me the top zero (instead of all) counts.

Comment: Changing the default value of a default parameter, or changing whether a parameter can be provided as default parameter.  In a discussion on whether to allow to pass the second parameter of `dict.get()` as keyword parameter `default`, even that change was dismissed as backward-incompatible:  Classes deriving from `dict` may have give it a different name, so they wouldn't work as drop-in replacements for a `dict` any more if people started using the `default` name.

Comment: Hmm, I don't no any instance in the Python standard library where `None` is implicitly considered as zero.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Off-hand I don't know of one either (and don't have time to look right now), but the truthiness of both is `False`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the real problem with most_common(): the fact that it copies the full data into the new variable. It would be nice to have a most_common generator which iterates over data without copying it.

Comment: @Dennis: If you think about it, `most_common()` _has_ to copy the data so it can bed used as a key of an associated value (the count)—it's a subclass of `dict` after all.

Comment: @martineau. Well, `most_common()` is analogous to `dict.items()`: it copies all the data. But `dict` has also `iteritems()`, which is a generator over the same data, so it doesn't copy anything. It would be nice to have the same generator for `Counter`.

Comment: @Dennis: No, it's not analogous to `dict.items()` which simply has to yield (key, value) pairs from the `dict` instance. Instead `most_common()` effectively has to create a list of those pairs so they can be sorted together all at once. If you want to iteratively access the contents of that sorted list, simply wrap the method call with `iter()` as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @martineau I see your point. Well, Counter could sort the elements as they are added (or keep an order index), and then could have iter_most_common method, which iterates over those. But if it keeps elements unsorted (which I assume is the case), then yes, it needs to collect them and sort in memory.